# "google-direction" tag should be renamed to "google-directions"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

On Stack Overflow there is a tag [google-direction](/questions/tagged/google-direction). The actual product name according to Google is [Google Directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/), so the tag should be renamed accordingly to correctly match the product name. (There is no product called "Google Direction").

Therefore, can a moderator rename the [google-direction](/questions/tagged/google-direction) tag to [google-directions](/questions/tagged/google-directions)?